# How to install xacml and XACML mediation in wso2am-2.5.0

Tags: authorization, wso2-api-manager, xacml, balana, wso2-identity-server

How to install XACML and XACML mediation in wso2am-2.5.0

I am following this [link](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/use-of-wso2-api-manager-to-validate-fine-grained-policy-decisions-using-xacml/)

XACML is displaying with three times with different version but XACML Mediator is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the repo URL added in feature installation. Using this URL 'http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/' instead of 'http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/turing/' might help.